# refinerycms iframe dont show in my webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, iframe, refinerycms, wymeditor

My webpages don't show any iframe or embed html code. The wymeditor preview show the page perfectly, the information is stored on the database, but the page show nothing. I'm using Rails 4.2.6 and the newest refinerycms version.

I've tried everything, this guy had the same problem https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/1991 but the solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason the fix doesn't work anymore is because of the deprecation of the allowed_tags/allowed_attributes settings.  See info on that [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#rails-html-sanitizer)

However, if you trust the content, you could just skip the sanitization process altogether by overriding the default template.

```
bundle exec rake refinery:override view=refinery/pages/*
```

That will dump a couple of views into your project.  Change the show template to something like this to render without sanitizing:

```
<%= raw(@page.content_for(:body) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

We sanitize the `SectionPresenter` since Refinery CMS `3.0.2` and we are aware of whitelist problems, there is a pending pull request to help devs to add more tags in your `whitelist` like probably `iframe`.

Please test this pull request to see if it fixed your problem : https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/pull/3164